# Unable to verified Rest HookSubscription in infusionsfoft

Tags: php, rest, api, webhooks, infusionsoft

I'm new in infusionsoft. Presently I had subscribed `contact.add` and `contact.edit` webhooks, but both have "Unverified" Status. So for that I'm using the below api to verify it. But I can't verified it.

```
https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/hooks/{key}/verify?access_token={token}
```

Also I'm getting **200 OK** in the response.

Why can't I verify it?

Answer (score 1):

```
I had successfully verified web hooks with the below way,

1. resthookManager.php

    <?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
$infusionsoft = new \Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft(array(
    'clientId' => '',
    'clientSecret' => '',
    'redirectUri' => '',
));
// By default, the SDK uses the Guzzle HTTP library for requests. To use CURL,
// you can change the HTTP client by using following line:
// $infusionsoft->setHttpClient(new \Infusionsoft\Http\CurlClient());
// If the serialized token is available in the session storage, we tell the SDK
// to use that token for subsequent requests.
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $infusionsoft->setToken(unserialize($_SESSION['token']));
}
// If we are returning from Infusionsoft we need to exchange the code for an
// access token.
if (isset($_GET['code']) and !$infusionsoft->getToken()) {
    $infusionsoft->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = serialize($infusionsoft->getToken());
}
function resthookManager($infusionsoft) {
    $resthooks = $infusionsoft->resthooks();
    // first, create a new task
    $resthook = $resthooks->create([
        'eventKey' => 'contact.add',
        'hookUrl' => 'http://infusionsoft.app/verifyRestHook.php'
    ]);
    var_dump($resthook);
    $resthook = $resthooks->find($resthook->id)->verify();
    return $resthook;
}
if ($infusionsoft->getToken()) {
    try {
        $resthook = resthookManager($infusionsoft);
    }
    catch (\Infusionsoft\TokenExpiredException $e) {
        // If the request fails due to an expired access token, we can refresh
        // the token and then do the request again.
        $infusionsoft->refreshAccessToken();
        // Save the serialized token to the current session for subsequent requests
        $_SESSION['token'] = serialize($infusionsoft->getToken());
        $resthook = resthookManager($infusionsoft);
    }
    var_dump($resthook);
}
else {
    echo '<a href="' . $infusionsoft->getAuthorizationUrl() . '">Click here to authorize</a>';
}

2. verifyRestHook.php

    <?php
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
$infusionsoft = new \Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft(array(
    'clientId' => '',
    'clientSecret' => '',
    'redirectUri' => '',
));
// In order to verify the endpoint, we need to return the X-Hook-Secret header.
// By default, the autoverify() function will set the proper header, but if you
// pass false as the first argument to autoverify(false) the function will simply
// return the header value for you to set as you please (handy if you are using
// a PHP class or framework that manages requests for you
$infusionsoft->resthooks()->autoverify();
return;

Thanks..
```